# H3 and P don't line-break

Tags: html, css

Normally, putting an `<h3>bla bla</h3>` and then a `<p>bladdibladdi</p>` should naturally line-break, because of them both being blocks.

But using this code apparently doesn't and now I've spent far too much time on this simple problem, so I'm posting it here.

```css
/* *, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}*/

a {
  color: #C21351;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 40pt;
  color: #C21351;
}

header {
  margin: 0.5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

header div {
  margin: 0px 1% 0px 0px;
}

#userinfo {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#userinfo h3 {
  font-size: 20pt;
}

#userinfo p {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

.nyttjobb {
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  background-image: url('images/nyttjobb.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nyttjobb:hover {
  background-image: url('images/nyttjobbhover.png');
}

.listaalla {
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  background-image: url('images/listaalla.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}

.listaalla:hover {
  background-image: url('images/listaallahover.png');
}

.tablecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.contentcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
  background-color: rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.39);
}

.tablerow {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: stretch;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.action {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
}

.rowhidden {
  display: none;
}

.rowflex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.expand {
  background-image: url(images/rowexpand.png);
  width: 61px;
  height: 61px;
}

.contract {
  height: 61px;
  background-image: url(images/rowcontract.png);
  width: 61px;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

h3,
p {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#editerajobbmain {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: #C21351;
}


/* Lägg till jobb */

#formcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.forminput {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

label {
  color: #C21351;
}

input[type=datetime],
input[type=text],
input[type=tel],
input[type=email],
input[type=datetime],
input[type=password] select,
textarea,
.user,
.password {
  border: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
  height: 48px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

textarea {
  height: 192px;
}

.cell select {
  width: 150px;
}

#regnummer {}


/* LOGIN form */

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.wrapper p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.loginform label {
  color: #C21351;
  display: block;
  font-size: 30pt;
}

.loginform input[type=datetime],
.loginform input[type=text],
.loginform input[type=tel],
.loginform input[type=email],
.loginform input[type=datetime],
.loginform input[type=password],
.loginform select,
.loginform textarea,
.loginform .user,
.loginform .password {
  border: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30pt;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.loginform input[type=submit] {
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 30pt;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  height: 100px;
}


/* Footer */

footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  /*height: 150px;*/
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #C21351;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 0;
}

footer a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #252525;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer div {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

footer ul {
  padding: 0px;
}

footer ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* Cookies!!! */

.cookie-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.39);
  color: #f5f6fa;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 16px rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.39);
  z-index: 5;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.cookie-container.active {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.cookie-content a {
  color: #f5f6fa;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cookie-content a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.cookie-content {
  height: 360px;
  background-color: #2f3640;
  padding: 32px;
  margin: 300px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.cookie-btn {
  background: #C21351;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 12px 48px;
  font-size: 30pt;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="table">
    <div class="tablecontainer">
      <form id="">
        <div class="contentcontainer">

          <!-- Använd javascript:void(null) för att sidan inte ska hoppa runt när man klickar. -->

          <div class="">
            <div class="cell">
              <h3>Registreringsnummer</h3>
              <p>regnummer</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h3>Telefon</h3>
              <p>kontakttel</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h3>E-post</h3>
              <p>kontaktepost</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h3>Jobbtyp</h3>
              <p>jobbtyp</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <select>
                <option value="">
                  status
                </option>
                <option>Kontaktad</option>
                <option>Klar</option>
                <option>Påbörjad</option>
                <option>Inkommen</option>
                <option>Avslutad</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h3>Information</h3>
              <p>info</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h3>Arbetstid</h3>
              <p>jobbtid</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h3>Offererat pris</h3>
              <p>pris</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h3>Reservdelar</h3>
              <p>reservdelar</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

I know it's not the tidiest of coding. It's not the issue right now. That comes later when everything is working as intended.

Comment: Developer tools are your best bet when you get unexplained styling behavior. Using deve tools (commonly F12) inspect the element with the odd styling and see what is being overridden,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display:flex on .cell is doing it. Remove that to make that class like this:

```
.cell {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man. Sometimes we just go blind, I guess.